# Why can you not concatenate an empty string in Kotlin's print function?

Tags: kotlin

Why does `println(something + " " + something)` not work in Kotlin? I know `println(something, something)` does not work either. Is there some way around this?

Comment: I know nothing about Kotlin, but I did literally a single Google search and found a page that answers your question exactly. https://www.journaldev.com/19757/kotlin-print-println-readline-scanner-repl Downvoting for lack of effort.

Comment: Use println("$something $something") where something is a variable name.

Comment: Right of course, my bad, I was just desperate at this point. Sorry again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only concatenate Strings with the `+` operator. For other classes, it might be defined as performing addition, or adding an element to a list, or (usually) not defined at all.

When you pass a single item to `println()`, it calls `toString()` on it internally. If you want to concatenate the string representations of multiple objects, you must call `toString()` on them first:

```
println(something.toString() + " " + something2.toString())
```

Or use string template syntax:

```
println("$something $something2")
```